# 32 bit vs. 64 bit Ubuntu on a Samsung Netbook NC-210

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, samsung

does anyone know if it is possible to run a 64-bit Ubuntu on a Samsung Netbook NC-210? And would there be advantages of using a 64 bit Ubuntu over the 32 bit version? 
In the MS Windows world this netbook is limited to using only the 32-bit versions of MS's operating systems. Does the same apply to Ubuntu/Linux?

Edit: cat /proc/cpuinfo says:

```
    processor   : 0
    vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
    cpu family  : 6
    model       : 28
    model name  : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N550   @ 1.50GHz
    stepping    : 10
    microcode   : 0x107
    cpu MHz     : 1000.000
    cache size  : 512 KB
    physical id : 0
    siblings    : 4
    core id     : 0
    cpu cores   : 2
    apicid      : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fpu     : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level : 10
    wp      : yes
    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm dtherm
    bugs        :
    bogomips    : 2992.30
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:

    ... and so on up to proc # 3
```

So I would say it is limited to 32 bit due to address sizes.

BUT what makes me really wonder is the fact, that at this very moment I am running 16.04 amd-64 bit off a USB stick on this very machine.

Comment: If you can only run a 32bit Windows then the same restriction applies to a Linux system - it is a 32bit processor and won't work with 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

You said that the system could only ever run 32bit Windows.

That likely means your processor in the system is a 32-bit processor.  The same limitations apply here.

You are limited by the architecture of the CPU in the system, which is 32-bit only.